# CollectionProperty to store Node or NodeGroup

Tags: python, materials

Can CollectionProperty be used to store a NodeGroup or Node?. If so, how?
I would like to be able to access it as fast and performance-friendly as possible.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/101794/55508

That would be an answer to this, but still Idk how to call it later on a class or function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Define, populate, draw**

Here I've extended answer from link posted in question with example on how to define, register and populate a collection `xxxx` on the scene object, containing all nodes from all materials in blend file.

Prepends the draw method to the text editor footer.

Note code is also updated for version 2.8x.

```
import bpy


class MyPropertyGroup(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    material : bpy.props.PointerProperty(
        name="Material",
        type=bpy.types.Material,
    )

    @property
    def node(self):
        mat = self.material
        if mat:
            return mat.node_tree.nodes.get(self.name)


# draw function
def draw(self, context):
    scene = context.scene
    layout = self.layout

    # NOTE: item is an instance of MyPropertyGroup
    for item in scene.xxxx:
        layout.prop(item, "material")
        node_selection_active = item.material is not None and item.material.use_nodes
        row = layout.row()
        row.enabled = node_selection_active
        if node_selection_active:
            row.prop_search(item, "name", item.material.node_tree, "nodes")
        else:
            row.prop(item, "name")

#register the class
bpy.utils.register_class(MyPropertyGroup)

# make it a collection on the scene for example        
bpy.types.Scene.xxxx = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyPropertyGroup)

# test it, get the scene
scene = bpy.context.scene
# clear it
scene.xxxx.clear()
# populate it with all nodes of all materials.
for m in bpy.data.materials:
    if m.use_nodes:
        for n in m.node_tree.nodes:
            item = scene.xxxx.add()
            item.name = n.name
            item.material = m
# draw in footer            
bpy.types.TEXT_HT_footer.prepend(draw)
```

Comment: Let's say I would like to have two lists, one for the materials and another for the nodes of the selected material from the first list.
My main problem right now is that I don't know how to fill the arguments of 
row.template_list without PointerProperty since nodes can't be stored there.

Thanks a million